# TFS Assign Work Item By STATE ... with conditions

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Our TFS is currently set up to assign a work item to our Tester (by capacity planning role) when the item goes from **Active** to **Resolved** `state`.

This is great, but it doesn't go far enough.  When the Tester moves the item from **Resolved** to either **Closed** (tested and verified fixed) or **Active** (failed testing) I want to reassign the item *back* to whoever most recently transitioned it from **Active** to **Resolved**.

This way the person who fixed it is still associated with it when the defect is closed (get credit for your work) or if you didn't pass testing it gets reassigned back to the person that will be re-doing the work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your requirement can be achieved.

> 1. Automatically change AssignedTo field to a user when State field changes from Active to Resolved.

Assuming you have installed TFS Power Tool. You can modify the Transition from Active to Resolved (my example is from To Do to In Progress) by **adding AssignedTo field and rules to this Transition**:

[image]

The XML file should be like:

```
<Transition from="To Do" to="In Progress">
  <ACTIONS>
    <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork" />
  </ACTIONS>
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Work started" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
      <DEFAULT from="value" value="{Tester}" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</Transition>
```

In my example, when the State changes from To Do to In Progress, the AssignedTo field will change to Tester.

> 2. When the Tester changes State from Resolved to Active, the AssignedTo field will change back to whoever most recently change it
>      from Active to Resolved.

First, you need to customize a field to get ChangedBy value. In my example, I've customized a field named copy, the XML file looks like:

```
<FieldDefinition name="copy" refname="copy.copy" type="String">
  <COPY from="field" field="System.ChangedBy" />
</FieldDefinition>
```

Then, similar to the item 1 above, you need to modify the Transition from Resolved to Active to (my example is from In Progress to To Do), the XML file looks like:

```
<Transition from="In Progress" to="To Do">
  <ACTIONS>
    <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork" />
  </ACTIONS>
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Work stopped" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
      <COPY from="field" field="copy.copy" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</Transition>
```

In my example, when the State changes from In Progress to To Do, the AssignedTo field will change to the user who change it most recently.

Answer (score 0):

Might be there Solution for your question, but what I know is you don't need that just to see the person will be associate with it .

This is because if you see on right pane,when someone check-in the code for that work-item, or makes changes to that and saves the work-item ,automatically TFS shows in arrow with Steps continuously what have been done and by whom with date

and after failed testing. Developer who checked-in the code or try to solve that issue you can just select that developer name on dropdown on assign

I guess you were almost wanting similar the way i told but again if not forgive me.

Thanks,

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean, but I want the Assigned To field to be automatically adjusted as I described whenever the work item State changes.